# Extracting words from a string into dynamic 2D char array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, tokenize, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamic char array that contains a string. I'm trying to extract all the words from this string into a dynamic 2d char array. Here's my code:

```
int rows = 1;
char *input_words = malloc((rows)*sizeof(char)); 
input_words = lowerCase(getInputWords(MAX_LINE_LEN, input_file)); //retrieves a string of words
char **input_words_tokenized = malloc((wordCount(input_words))*sizeof(char)); 

for(i = 0; i < wordCount(input_words); i++) {
    input_words_tokenized[i] = malloc(MAX_KEY_LEN*sizeof(char)); 
}


char *t = strtok(input_words, " ");
j = 0;
while(t) {
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(t); i++) {
        strcpy(&input_words_tokenized[j][i], &t[i]);
        printf("%c", input_words_tokenized[j][i]);
    }
    j++;

    t = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

In my output, `input_words_tokenized[j][i]` only contains the first word or token from `input_words`. Why aren't the remaining words being tokenized and stored into `input_words_tokenized[j][i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one issue.

Incorrect size calculation.

```
char **input_words_tokenized = 
    malloc((wordCount(input_words))*sizeof(char));
    // wrong type                          ^--^
```

Instead of sizing to the hopefully matching type, size to the referenced type.  It is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
char **input_words_tokenized = 
    malloc((wordCount(input_words)) * sizeof *input_words_tokenized);
    //                                       ^--------------------^
```